# Modify Grid footer information ("On Hand X, Available Y, ...")

Tags: acumatica

Is there any way with a customization to modify the information area at the footer of a grid particularly the Sales Order Entry > Document Details grid that displays On Hand & Availability information for the Current SOLine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public virtual void SOLine_Availability_FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e, PXFieldSelecting invokeBaseHandler)
    {
        invokeBaseHandler(sender, e);
        e.ReturnValue = "Hey There!";

    }
```

Availability seems to be a common descriptor/field for several line level DACs

Comment: I'm not wanting to change the value of the Availability field but rather add new custom fields for the particular item to the footer area when a line is selected. I currently have the custom item-specific fields as their own grid columns but that is unnecessary for their purpose which is why I'm looking for how to modify them in the footer.

Comment: I think what Patrick Chen answered should solve your initial question. You should be able to add more text to the existing Availability field to display your values as Patrick Mentioned.

Comment: I think if you want to add more fields, you're going to have to do something drastic.  The status field is a built-in feature of the aspx grid.  I think the best answer is to try and concatenate your data to the stock info in Availability as Brendan suggested..

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party here, but to ADD onto the existing display, you simply need to add onto the `e.ReturnValue`, instead of replacing it.

```
public virtual void SOLine_Availability_FieldSelecting(PXCache sender, PXFieldSelectingEventArgs e, PXFieldSelecting invokeBaseHandler)
{
    invokeBaseHandler(sender, e);
    e.ReturnValue = e.ReturnValue + " My Added Text!";
}
```