# How to add Availability(SO) to the Purchase Order page

Tags: acumatica

Good day

I need to add the functionality(Availability), that shows the qty on hand,.. on the bottom of the Sales Order page, on the Purchase Order page.

Is the possible to do it and how?

[image: Screanshot]
In short, I need to add Availability to the bottom of the Purchase page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous posts related to the adding availability to pages. Please refer to these posts for the best answer:

[How to display product availability in Opportunity Products Grid footer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45025533/how-to-display-product-availability-in-opportunity-products-grid-footer)

[How do I add the Inventory Availability Status to Custom Grid like SO301000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55249309/how-do-i-add-the-inventory-availability-status-to-custom-grid-like-so301000)

[Modify Grid footer information (“On Hand X, Available Y, …”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41514275/modify-grid-footer-information-on-hand-x-available-y)